# How does dimming of driverless LEDs work?

Tags: led

I have read [this](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/driverless-led-lights) article which describes different generations of driverless LEDs. Now there are also driverless and at the same time flicker free LEDs on the market (for example [here](https://productfinder.illuxtron.com/product/16756/Surface---mounted/lido-100-hvfd-600lm-22003000k-cri93-40-triac-black/)). So what are the state of the art techniques to get flicker free dimming with *driverless* LEDs? How do the plots of the output current look like in a dimmed state? I know that with drivers one can use PWM or AM dimming, and I know how the plots look like in this case, but how does it work in the driverless case?

Comment: LEDs also do dim as a function of voltage- its just over a very small range compared to that of an incandescent.  Linearizing that LED range onto a typical dimmer range is not impossible.  Need to know light vs voltage curve of the LED.

Comment: @Abel I'm honestly not sure what the OP is asking. But I do have a comment to your comment. Human intensity perception is \$\approx\$ logarithmic, in order that we can see in everything from equatorial daylight in a desert to starlilght in a woods. LEDs can be arranged to dim over a similar range of orders of magnitude in apparent brightness to humans. It just requires geometric methods. But this has little to do with light vs voltage of the LED, which I don't even look at when doing something like this.

Comment: "Driverless" what are all the components doing in the circuit?

Comment: @Gil "Driverless" probably just sounds better than "integrated driver" (which might make it seem like someone put a driver in to take control of your [hardware] away from you...)